# Json convertor to write object to string property

Tags: c#, json, json.net

The scenario is the following: I have some classes part of an sdk and in a type hierarchy, I cannot  don't want to mess around with them. I also have a json returned from a service.

The issue (and I considered it actually a bug in the service, but this is out of my control) is that some properties in the json are returned as an object while the property in the class is defined as a string. So for example

```
class MyClass {
     string? Foo { get; set; }
     string? Bar { get; set; }
}
```

But the json looks like:

```
{
     "Foo": "{\"SomeProperty\": 123 }",
     "Bar": {
               "SomeProperty": 456
            } 
}
```

The property Foo is correct and give no issue, Bar on the other hand is not correct.

When deserializing the json

```
var jsonObject = JObject.Load(reader);
var obj = jsonObject.ToObject<MyClass>();
```

this fails with the error: **Error reading string. Unexpected token: StartObject.**

And while I totally agree with the error, I would like to make this work. Bar should just contain the serialised object (string).

To be clear: I don't want a custom serialisation for MyClass. I am looking for some kind of custom convertor that can handle the mismatch for any property defined as a string but encountered as an object.

Comment: What is the problem with creating a converter that acts just like you described?

Comment: @GoodNightNerdPride I was not yet successful in writing that convertor.

Comment: Could you show us what you got and point out the issues?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a quick implementation for such a StringConverter.

```
public class StringConverter : JsonConverter<string>
{
    public override string ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, string existingValue, bool hasExistingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        switch (reader.TokenType)
        {
            case JsonToken.String:
                return existingValue;
            case JsonToken.StartObject:
                return JObject.ReadFrom(reader).ToString();
            default:
                throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, string value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        writer.WriteValue(value);
    }
}
```

How to use

```
var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings();
var converter = new StringConverter();

settings.Converters.Add(converter);

var json = "{ \"data1\": \"d1\", \"data2\": { \"prop\": \"d2\"}, \"data3\": \"d3\" }";

var item = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Test>(json, settings);

public class Test
{
    public string data1 { get; set; }

    public string data2 { get; set; }

    public string data3 { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: This is kind of what I had, but isn't working on the real data. I will add some more details and a full example next week.

Comment: The data must be different from what you have indicated in your post, then.

Answer (score 0):

### Conver all expressions to string first then deserialize them to the corresponding object.

**Create Class to the corresponding expression.**

```
public class MyFoo
{
    public int? Expression { get; set; }
}
```

**Add it in *MyClass***

```
public class MyClass
{
   public string? Foo { get; set; }
   [NotMapped]
   public MyFoo? RealFoo { get; set; }

}
```

**After deserializing to MyClass, deserialize the property *Foo* to the property *RealFoo***

**Example:**

```
string json = @"{
     ""Foo"": ""{\""Expression\"": 123 }""

}";

JsonTextReader reader = new JsonTextReader(new StringReader(json));
var jsonObject = JObject.Load(reader);
var obj = jsonObject.ToObject<MyClass>();
JsonTextReader newreader = new JsonTextReader(new StringReader(obj?.Foo??""));

var jsonObject2 = JObject.Load(newreader);
obj.RealFoo = jsonObject2.ToObject<MyFoo>();
Console.WriteLine(obj?.RealFoo?.Expression??0);
```

Output => 123

**Note**: it's not the best solution but it's a work around to deal with the bug in the service you use

Comment: I cannot edit the classes. They are defined in a external nuget. The real issue occurs in a list of an abstract type where each item is one of the subclasses. I really need it to solve it while converting leaving the json and the target types as is.

Comment: you can add simple check if( obj.Bar is not string) { //convert it to some class }

Answer (score 0):

Create additional DTO class:

```
class MyClassDto
{
    public string? Foo { get; set; }
    public object? Bar { get; set; }
}
```

Load firstly to DTO, then convert `Bar` object to string.
After that create `MyClass` instance from DTO.

```
var dto = jsonObject.ToObject<MyClassDto>();
dto.Bar = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dto.Bar);

var obj = new MyClass
{
    Foo = dto.Foo,
    Bar = dto.Bar.ToString()
};
```

Is this solution acceptable to you?